# Adding permissions when user is saved in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I'm creating an instance of a `User` object. The creation itself is a standard `User.objects.create_user` call and that works ok - user is created. After that, I'm trying to add a few permissions to him or her:

```
for name in ('view_restaurant', 'change_restaurant', 'delete_restaurant',
             'view_meal', 'add_meal', 'change_meal', 'delete_meal',
             'view_order', 'delete_order',
             'view_historicalorder', 'add_historicalorder', 'change_historicalorder', 
             'view_orderitem',
             'view_historicalorderitem', 
             'view_restaurantemployee', 'add_restaurantemployee', 'change_restaurantemployee', 'delete_restaurantemployee'):
    permission = Permission.objects.get(codename=name)
    print(permission is None)
    user.user_permissions.add(permission)
    user.save()
    print(user.has_perm(permission))
```

As you can see, in the last line I'm checking whether the user was assigned with an appropriate permission, and few lines above I'm checking if permission is `None`. The result is that the permission object is never none, but `user.has_perm` call always returns false. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling [has_perm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm) incorrectly.  It expects a string in this format

```
"<app label>.<permission codename>"
```

As an aside, may I recommend to simplify your code like so:

```
codenames = 'view_restaurant', 'change_restaurant', ...
perms = Permission.objects.filter(codename__in=codenames)
user.user_permissions.add(*perms)
```

Comment: Thanks for both suggestions!